# AngularJS ui-router, how to get the name of the targeted state in the resolve object of an abstract partent state?

Tags: angularjs

I am using ui-router and I have child states and an abstract one - the parent.

Now, I want to be able to do some user role management and I want to do it in a single place, for all roots.

The best way to do it, is in the parent's state resolve object.$stateProvider

Here, i do this to mange app width authentication data.

The question is, how do I get the targeted state from the resolve function of an abstract state?

```
    .state('section', {
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        resolve: {

            // Auth & role management middleware.
            UserData: ['$q', '$stateParams', 'Session', function ($q, $stateParams, Session) {

                // HOW DO I GET THE DESTINATION ROUTE HERE.
                $state.current.name - returns null
                $stateParams  - is an empty object.
                // ANY IDEAS?

                var userData;
                userData = Session.getUserData();
                if (userData.token) {
                    return userData;
                }
                return $q.reject('login');
            }]
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

state hasn't updated when inside resolve.

My workaround by far is listen to '$stateChangeStart' event by

`$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', callback)`

this event is emitted before resolve, and second param passed to callback is `toState` which has the info you need.

You can put this logic into your `Session service`

Comment: It's not the best idea from the architecture point of view and future compatibility, but due to the lack of other alternatives, it's a nice workaround! Thanks )

Answer (score 0):

I know this is this old, but use `$state.next.name` to get the targeted state.